# Rename file with version number to file without version number

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to rename file-name-1.2.3.war to file-name.war

I have tried various Ansible modules that would rename a file, but, I could not figure out how to get list of files and remove the version number in the name of the file.

```
- name: "List *.war if exists on {{ lookup('env','WORKSPACE') }}"
  local_action: 
    module: find
    paths: "{{ lookup('env','WORKSPACE') }}"
    patterns:
      - "[a-z\\-]*[\\[0-9\\.\\-]*.war" 
  register: files_matched
- name: "DEBUG: List *.war if exists on {{ lookup('env','WORKSPACE') }}"  
  debug:
    msg: 
      - "{{ files_matched.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Expected result should rename [a-z\-]*[\[0-9\.\-]*.war to [a-z\-]*[.\-]*.war

Comment: Do you have to do it just with **Ansible**?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your expression is just fine, we might want to add some capturing groups,

```
([a-z-]*)([0-9.-]*)(\..*)
```

and make a replacement with `$1$3`.

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/pdY9MH/1/)

I removed the escaping for demoing reason, you can just add those where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to NOT have a `-` at the end of a file name, use this:

```
([a-z-]*[a-z])([0-9.-]*)(\..*)
```

And replace it with:

```
\1\3
```

Test it [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/pdY9MH/2)

---

(this is an improved version of the answer provided by @Emma)

Answer (score 0):

If your filename can not contain consecutive hyphens and not at the start or at the end, you could use a capturing group for what you want to keep matching `[a-z]+` followed by a repeating pattern to make sure the hyphen is not at the end.

Then match what you want to remove by matching the `-` and 1+ digits again followed by a repeating pattern to match a dot and a digit so that there can not be consecutive dots and not at the start and the end.

At the end use a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is `.war`

If your filename itself can also contain word characters like digits and an underscore you could also use `\w+`.

In the replacement use what you want to keep which is in the first capturing group `\1`

```
(\w+(?:-\w+)*)-\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?=\.war\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capturing group 1

  - `\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars followed by 0+ times a `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `-\d+` Match `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?=\.war\b)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is `.war` followed by a word boundary to prevent war being part of a larger word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6dQKmd/1)